# Jetty-Jersey how to handle requests behind reverse proxy?

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm using:

- `Jetty 9.4.12.v20180830`
- `Jersey 2.28`

Is there a recommended way to decorate our web server to handle requests behind a reverse proxy?

I.e. relative paths and `Location` headers do not come out correctly because the proxy has a different host and the routes are different.

I might expect to find filters to handle the `(x-)forwarded*` headers.
For example, I found this one ([qaware/x-forwarded-filter](https://github.com/qaware/x-forwarded-filter)) but it is not a standard library...

Answer (score 0):

Configure your reverse proxy to provide the `Forwarded` (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239) request header to Jetty.

Then add the `ForwardedRequestCustomizer` to your `HttpConfiguration` within your `ServerConnector`.

That should be it.

Comment: I see, thank you. Does that customizer handle modifying response headers too? Things like Location headers so they work in front of the proxy (assuming the proxy fills out the correct forwarded headers)?

Comment: The ForwardedRequestCustomizer updates the internals of the request, specifically for the authority of the request (makes it match the user-agent intended destination, not the actual destination), which all of the generated response locations are based off of.  So in a round-about way, yes, it causes a change in the response.

Comment: Oh, and update your version of Jetty (consider 9.4.35), as there's been hundreds of improvements to ForwardedRequestCustomizer since 9.4.12.

Comment: Thanks, I spent some time today trying 9.4.35 with the ForwardedRequestCustomizer added. Another hurdle for me is that our Envoy proxy cuts out part of the route. E.g. a client request to "/a/b/c" arrives at the server after the proxy as "/b/c". So location comes back as "host:port/b/c" which doesn't work in front of the proxy (it has to be "host:port/a/b/c"). Is there a way to handle that?